# Neither Positioned's width or SizedBox's width works inside a stack widget - Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Title Text'),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Stack(children: [
        Column(
          children: const [
            Text('short content'),
          ],
        ),
        const Positioned(
            top: 100,
            width: 320,
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 320,
              height: 50,
              child: ColoredBox(color: Colors.red),
            ))
      ])),
    );
```

[image]

I need the red box taking almost the entire screen with, but it flows the text width. How should I make this work?

Comment: what is the issue here? can you explain more?

Comment: @eamirho3ein the width of redbox equals to the text in column, which is far less than '320' value specified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap *all* children of the stack with either `Align` or `Positioned` so that the `Stack` can properly lay them out.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Title Text'),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            /// The column is now positioned.
            Positioned(
              top: .0,
              left: .0,
              child: Column(
                children: const [
                  ColoredBox(color: Colors.amber, child: Text('short content'))
                ],
              ),
            ),
            const Positioned(
              top: 100.0,
              width: 320.0,
              height: 50.0,
              child: ColoredBox(color: Colors.red),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I think this answer inspire me to dig futher to the (Stack and RenderStack) api document which explains more why this happens.  1. stack layouts non-positioned children and sizes itself to enclose all the non-positioned children. If there are no non-positioned children, the stack becomes as large as possible. 2. Positioned children are taken care of and anything outside the flex box will be clipped.

Comment: I prefer to use ```Positioned.fill``` in case the text is too long and won't be displayed out side of the view

Comment: @夜一林风 Yes, widgets like `Stack`, `Row` and `Column` should usually lay out their children using the associated layout classes: `Positioned`, `Expanded`, etc. The issue with long text can be tested on `Row` as well, as you described. For example, you might have overflow (yellow and black lines) instead of just clipping if you don't use `Expanded` on text that exceeds the bounds of the parent widget.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your `Stack` with `SizedBox`:

```
SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Stack(
          clipBehavior: Clip.none,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: const [
                  Text('short content'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
                top: 100,
                right: 0,
                left: 0,
                child: Container(
                  height: 50,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ))
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

[image]

Comment: @夜一林风 was it what you want?